# I can't cancel orders. Integrity Constraint Violation

Tags: product, database, orders, error

Whenever i try to delete an order, by entering the order and then clicking cancel, i get a "The order has not been cancelled" Message.

I tried deleting the order from the list, and issuing an action from it and i got this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databasename`.`catalog_product_entity_int`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_INT_ENTT_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DEL)


Trace:
#0 /home/cashapoy/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home/cashapoy/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/cashapoy/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/cashapoy/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 /home/cashapoy/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 /home/cashapoy/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1910): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#6 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php(1463): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertOnDuplicate('catalog_product...', Array, Array)
#7 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Action.php(84): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_processAttributeValues()
#8 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Action.php(72): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Action->updateAttributes(Array, Array, 0)
#9 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Status.php(203): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Action->updateAttributes(Array, Array, 0)
#10 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1167): Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status->updateProductStatus('541', 0, 1)
#11 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php(1139): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->registerCancellation()
#12 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(359): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->cancel()
#13 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->massCancelAction()
#14 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('massCancel')
#15 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /home/cashapoy/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home/cashapoy/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

What exactly is going on and what can i do about it?

The product that once belonged to that order has been deleted, but this had not been an issue until yesterday.

Any idea why this could be happening?

Comment: You should do a backup of your database and use this tool to check your database http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/db-repair-tool You should do it on a database copy first to see errors which may apply. To use this tool, you need to install a clean magento with the same version of your current installation on a separate database then launch the script. You may find that you have bad foreign keys definition for example

Comment: I did run the database repair tool and to my joy, it found plenty of errors, which it promptly corrected. But, i still can't cancel those orders, for the same reasons...

Comment: Is Magento set to put the item's status back to 'In Stock' when order is cancelled. Check the System Configuration value under "System > Configuration > Catalog/Inventory > 
Set Items' Status to be In Stock When Order is Cancelled"

If you've deleted thew product, then clearly this can't happen

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, you have in `catalog_product_entity_int` a reference to a non existing product in `catalog_product_entity`.

I would say this is from a bad import.

You should check between these two tables ... just join and check for NULL values.